# How to create VBA Backup Script on the Specified Time

Tags: vba, excel

For example, I have an excel file saved in our network drive. On that file, I want to implement a solution that will enable an automatic backup for the time specified by the user.

For example:
File.xlsx

Script will backup this file every 10:00am, 4:00PM and 5:00am. Will that be possible?

Comment: Doing a timed task (copy the file somewhere) directly at the machine which is hosting the file, would be easier than "hoping" that someone works with this file at a given time...

Comment: Just an other suggestion, you can write some batch script in task scheduler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this sub below and just add your own backup-saving macro called `BackupFile`

```
Sub SetSchedule()

Application.OnTime TimeValue("5:00:00"), "BackupFile"

Application.OnTime TimeValue("10:00:00"), "BackupFile"

Application.OnTime TimeValue("16:00:00"), "BackupFile"

Application.OnTime TimeValue("23:59:00"), "SetSchedule"

End Sub
```

And call it from the open sub:

```
Sub Workbook_Open()

    Call SetSchedule

End Sub
```

Comment: What if I want to create a backup copy every the user will open the file? And append the backup filename with date and timestamp?

Comment: That would be different than setting a time schedule, but you would just call your backup macro from the workbook open event

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to create a Scheduled Task to run a batch or script file that will back up your file.

Here is are example parameters for the Scheduled Task.

> C:\Windows\System32\WScript.exe C:\Excel Files\backup.vbs"

Save this script as backup.vbs

**VBScript**

```
Const FolderName = "C:\Excel Files\"
Const FileName = "Data.xlsm"
Dim fso, NewName, sb

Set sb = CreateObject("System.Text.StringBuilder")
sb.AppendFormat "{0:yyyy-MM-dd} {0,8:t}", CDate(Now)

NewName = Replace(sb.ToString(), ":" ,".") & " - " & FileName

Set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")

fso.CopyFile FolderName & FileName, FolderName & NewName,True
```